# CSS Make scrollbar take its own space without overlaying the content of the page

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed toolbar having the buttons **btn1**, **btn2**, **btn3** (the toolbar is set to `display: flex`, `justify-content: space-between` and `position: fixed`), but unfortunately when the content of the page is too long that makes the scrollbar to appear, the scrollbar overrides a part of **btn3**. What should I do to make the scrollbar take its own space when it appears? Or make the toolbar automatically stretch a bit to leave some space for the scrollbar?

[image: Without scrollbar] Without scrollbar

[image: With scrollbar]With scrollbar (the three dots are behind the scrollbar)

```css
.Toolbar {
  height: 65px;
  background-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
  color: white;
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px -2px rgb(138, 138, 138);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.WholePage {
   height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="WholePage">
  <header class="Toolbar">
    <div>btn1</div>
    <div>btn2</div>
    <nav>btn3</nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: The button images are broken, all I get is `ImgBB error: Internal Server Error`. Please use the normal Stack Overflow way of adding images, which is by doing **Copy** and then **Paste** (of image data) in the Question editor.

Comment: @isherwood they could be anything (they're going to be buttons after I solve this issue) and still get overridden.

Comment: @isherwood I've reuploaded the images. Through "override" I meant "gets above visually", or something similar. The 3 dots get behind the scroll bar, therefore cannot be seen anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forcing the width to `100vw` pushes it behind the scrollbar. Use `100%` instead.

```css
.Toolbar {
  height: 65px;
  background-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px -2px rgb(138, 138, 138);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.WholePage {
  height: 1000px;
}

header>* {
  border: 2px solid pink;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="WholePage">
  <header class="Toolbar">
    <div>btn1</div>
    <div>btn2</div>
    <nav>btn3</nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue could come from the the `box-sizing`.

Try box sizing: `box-sizing: border-box;` for those buttons. I add .btn as my example for those three buttons.

```css
.btn {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

For the detail of the `box-sizing`, please check it as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing#box_sizes_with_content-box_and_border-box.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.toolbar {
  background-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px -2px rgb(138, 138, 138);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.toolbar div {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.whole-page {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="whole-page">
  <header class="toolbar">
    <div>btn1</div>
    <div>btn2</div>
    <div>btn3</div>
  </header>
</div>
```